# Why does Rhythmbox lose link to music folder located in NTFS partition?

Tags: ntfs, rhythmbox, music-player

Rhythmbox loses link to music folder located in NTFS partition even though all the NTFS partitions are mounted when Ubuntu 13.04 starts up. 
Why does this happen and how do I solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Opened Rhythmbox. From Edit>Preferences>Music clicked the Browse button. At the bottom-left corner of the pop-up menu clicked the + button and located the Music folder and added it to the list. "Watch my library file" checked. After shutting down and restarting the machine, launched Rhythmbox again and the songs are there now!